# Copy from remote to local repository

Tags: artifactory

I have a remote Maven-repository where I would like to copy a subset of the artifacts to a local repository on the same Artifactory server.

But the GUI does not display the copy-option when I right-click on the artifact and the copy-method in the REST API is only supported for local repository.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CopyItem

What is the best thing to do ? Do I need to download the artifacts and "republish" them to the local repository ? Is there not smarter way to copy the artifacts from a remote to a local repository ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method as a workaround:

1. [Retrieve artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveArtifact) from remote repository: `GET {remoteRepoKey}/{filePath}`. You don't have to save the file in your local machine. As by-product, the download process will copy the item from *remoteRepoKey* to *remoteRepoKey-cache*.
2. [Move item](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem) from *remoteRepoKey-cache* to your local repository: `POST /api/move/{remoteRepoKey-cache}/{filePath}?to=/{localRepoKey}/{filePath}`

It is not perfect, but it'll spare an upload to Artifactory and also the issues of storing a file in filesystem.

Further reading:

1. [What is a Remote repository and how does it work?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-a-remote-repository-and-how-does-it-work/)
2. [Remote Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories)
3. My blog: [Artifactory as a Caching Mechanism for Package Managers](https://jfrog.com/blog/artifactory-as-a-caching-mechanism-for-package-managers/)